# Get whole row using database package execute function

Tags: python, database, fastapi

I am using **databases** package in my fastapi app.  **databases** has execute and fetch functions, when I tried to return column values after inserting or updating using execute, it returns only the first value, how to get all the values without using fetch..

This is  my query

> INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3, col4)
>   VALUES ( val1, val2, val3, val4 ) RETURNING col1, col2;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES ( val1, val2, val3, val4 ) RETURNING (col1, col2);

you can use this query to get all columns

Answer (score 1):

You can use the query method having parameters of offset = 0 and limit = None to get all the columns

```
 db.query({YOUR TABLE OBJECT}).offset(0).limit(None).all()
```

You can refer in this link for more:
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/

if You are using mypy then you have to tell the intrepreter that limit value can be None

```
from typing import Optional
limit: Optional[int] = None
```

Comment: Am using raw queries and passing it to database execute function and it is returning only col1 value,..

Comment: And what about col2 value? because of this it should return col1 and col2 INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES ( val1, val2, val3, val4 ) **RETURNING col1, col2**;

Comment: returning only col1 value, i don't know to what's happening to other columns

Comment: am using databases package's execute function, it takes raw query as it's argument

Comment: Which database server language you are using like PostgreSQL,
MySQL or
SQLite

Comment: using PostgresSQL

Comment: then returning statement will display only the tuple which have been inserted in the table

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with this also, this was my query:

> INSERT INTO notes (text, completed) VALUES (:text, :completed) RETURNING notes.id, notes.text, notes.completed

Using `database.execute(...)` will only return the first column.

**But**.. using `database.fetch_one(...)` inserts the data and returns all the columns.

Hopes this helps